# Вырезать короткие слова и исключением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно вырезать короткие слова (до 2х символов), но оставить цифры. Делаю так:

`/\b([а-я]{0,2})\b/u`  + preg_replace.

Как мне  эту регулярку задать исключения?

Типа кг, см и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [негативный просмотр вперед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) например:

```
/\b(?!кг|см)([а-яё]{0,2})\b/ui
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/IvpGWQ/1

P.S. Группу захвата можно убрать https://regex101.com/r/IvpGWQ/2